# VBA Replace: Process current cell address w/o activation

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large set of polynomials (e.g: "X^2+3*X+7"). They are compiled as follows:
The second, third etc. column of my range("polynomials") contain the polynomials, whereas the first column contains the X values (in form of named ranges).

I managed to successfully write some code that toggles through the range and replaces any "x", either capitalized or not, with the actual X-values.

```
Private Sub Loop_Range()

Dim mrngLoop As Range 'this it the specific range which will be looped through to "activate" all its functions
Dim mrngCell As Range 'this is a cell within mrngLoop

Set mrngLoop = range("polynomials")

For Each mrngCell In mrngLoop.Cells
    mstrPolynomial = mrngCell.Value
    mstrPolynomial = Replace(mstrPolynomial, "X", "x")
    mstrPolynomial = Replace(mstrPolynomial, "x", Cells(mrngCell.Row, Range("polynomials").Column - 1).Value)
    mstrPolynomial = Replace(mstrPolynomial, ",", ".")
    mstrPolynomial = "=" & mstrPolynomial

    mrngCell.Value = strPolynomial

Next mrngCell 
End Sub
```

The code above works. But I tried to improve/shorten the code via implementing an array (@Scott Craner: thanks for the advice!):

```
Private Sub Loop_Array()

Dim marrLoop() As Variant 'this is an array which which will be looped through instead of the range to "activate" all its functions
Dim mintRow As Integer 'this is the row index of the array
Dim mintCol As Integer 'this is the column index of the array

marrLoop = Range("polynomial")
For mintRow = 1 To UBound(marrLoop, 1) ' First array dimension is rows.
    For mintCol = 2 To UBound(marrLoop, 2) ' Second array dimension is columns.

            marrLoop(mintRow, mintCol) = Replace(marrLoop(mintRow, mintCol), "X", "x")
            marrLoop(mintRow, mintCol) = Replace(marrLoop(mintRow, mintCol), ",", ".")
            marrLoop(mintRow, mintCol) = Replace(marrLoop(mintRow, mintCol), "x", marrLoop(mintRow, 1))
            marrLoop(mintRow, mintCol) = "=" & marrLoop(mintRow, mintCol)

    Next mintCol
Next mintRow
Range("polynomial") = marrLoop

End Sub
```

Comment: Short answer, no.  If you want to replace all the X with a different numbers then you will need to iterate through.  The bulk replace is made to replace everyone with the same value.

Comment: The slightly longer answer, load your values into an array, cycle through the array and do the replace, then load the array over the existing data.  It will be much quicker as you only reference the sheet twice, once to load the array and once to assign the values.  The cycle through the data will be very quick.  The fewer time the sheet is referenced the better.

Comment: @Scott Craner: Thanks for the quick reply! Also for the hints towards the array. This is definitely sth. I have to dig in a bit deeper.

Comment: Just to be sure. I cannot use
`Replace What:="X", Replacement:= ...`
for Arrays, right? I tried a couple of combinations but always receive missing object errors.

Comment: You would use something like this `Arr(1,1) = replace(Arr(1,1),"x",Arr(1,2))`